# Stackoverflow style date format

Tags: javascript, date, format

How to format the javascript `Date` object the way stackoverflow does it.

For example. `Aug 23 '10 at 23:35`

This is what I tried.

```
new Date(val.replace(' ','T')+'Z').toString().split('GMT')[0]
```

This works cross browser. But doesn't look neat.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you considered?  Where are you having problems?

Comment: Look at the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I tried some javascript. I posted this question. Since it is a complex problem for me.  Don't want to use moment.

Comment: Can you guys please remove the downvotes now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = [
      "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
      "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
      "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
      "Nov", "Dec"
    ];

    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var month = monthNames[monthIndex];
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2,3); 
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();


    return month+' '+day+" '"+year+' at '+hours+':'+minutes;
}
```

Comment: date.getFullYear(...).subString is not a function

Comment: Typo, it is `substring()`  and it should  read `getFullYear().toString().substring(2,3);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date();
var formattedDate = 
   (date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" })) + " " + 
   date.getDate() + " '" + (date.getFullYear() % 100);
var formattedTime = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
alert( formattedDate + " at " + formattedTime );
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc2ojcmu/).

Comment: That only works in user agents that support the [*ECMAScript Internationalization API*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-8), which means not Safari (at least). It is very simple and much more robust to create an appropriate format date string using plain javascript.